# How to keep untouched the #{} expression in spring configuratinn file?

Tags: java, spring

In my spring configuration file, I want to define a string with some variables till run time, but when I start the application, it throws a error saying:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'myid' defined in class path resource [spring-listview.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'base' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)`

```html
<bean id="myid" class="com.some.BasicWebUI">
  <property name="colsTemplate">
    <map>
      <entry key="NAME">
        <value>
          <![CDATA[<a href="#{base}/agent/detail?id=#{row.UID}">#{row.NAME}</a> ]]>
        </value>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The spring.version is 3.2.13.RELEASE

So, what can I do to keep the string in CDATA section keep untouched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution works, use `\` between `$` or `#` and `{` symbols

```
<bean id="myid" class="com.some.BasicWebUI">
  <property name="colsTemplate">
    <map>
      <entry key="NAME">
        <value>
          <![CDATA[<a href="#\{base}/agent/detail?id=#\{row.UID}">#\{row.NAME}</a> ]]>
        </value>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```